# Unable to resolve color value

Tags: android

I am trying to make my buttons change the color of their text when it is pressed but i ran into a problem that i cant solve. I get an error saying "unable to resolve color value" then it gives me the path to the file. here are my files im using

This one is in a new folder named color under resources and its called button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffff0000" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000ff" />
<item android:color="#ff000000" />
</selector>
```

And

```
<Button android:text="Main Menu" android:textColor="@color/button"
    android:layout_width="200px" android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
    android:layout_height="55px" android:layout_x="5dip"  
    android:layout_y="174dip"
    android:textSize="18px">
 </Button>
```

its driving me crazy if anybody could help me.

Comment: Its driving me crazy that the answer hasn't been accepted!

Answer (score 5):

I successfully did it like this:

Files:

```
/drawable/button_states.xml
/layout/main.xml
/values/colors.xml
```

**button_states.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/red" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/blue_background" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue_background">#FF2f74c3</color>
    <color name="white">#fefefe</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_states" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i just had to add the xml in the values folder!

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:background` instead.