# textColor: Unable to resolve color value

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a stange error (no [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926388/unable-to-resolve-color-value) won't help...)
I got a seperate layout for the tabbar. tabs_bg.xml is the layout. tab_text_selector.xml for the textColor and colors.xml. (Nameing of the colors might be misleading, but this is for testing)

If I click on the Graphical Layout, I got the error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@color/tab_unselected"

tabs_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/tabbar_background" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="15dip" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

tab_text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" 
            android:color="@color/tab_unselected" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" 
            android:color="@color/tab_unselected" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:color="@color/tab_selected" />
        <item android:color="@color/tab_selected" />
</selector>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="tab_selected">#036DAB</color>
    <color name="tab_unselected">#f36f25</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use uppercase letters in your colors instead of lowercase letters.

```
<color name="tab_unselected">#F36F25</color>
```